# How to fix a score DRL and kmodule.xml error

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I would like to embed the optaplanner 7.23.0.Final in my project to solve an optimization problem by a slightly modification of one of those examples. I can run all of the examples by manually running the main classes from IntelliJ without a problem. In the next step, I tried to call such a unmodified example main class from my actual project. Here, some kie.conf services are loaded and I run in an score DRL error, which I can't resolve. See log and error below.

I assume the .drl file has no error because the example runs when started manually.

I also assume that all references in the solver configs are set correct, because a change immediately leads to an error.

In some examples, there are "EasyScore"-methods additionally to the "Score DRL"-methods. The error refers definitively to the score DRL, because changing the score calculation method to one of the "EasyScore"-methods the optimization runs without errors. However, i would like prefer DRL because it is faster and already available for my desired example.

It seems the error is linked to a "kmodule.xml". Unfortunately I don't have such a file but it seems it's not required for solving the examples.

I tried to implement all possible "optaplanner", "drools", and "kie" dependencies in my pom file but the error stills exists.

In my project, I just tried to call optaplanner with this main method:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.app.NQueensHelloWorld.main(args);
  }
```

The error occurs during building the solver in the main method of the NQueensHelloWorld-Example:

```java
 SolverFactory<NQueens> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
                "org/optaplanner/examples/nqueens/solver/nqueensSolverConfig.xml");
        Solver<NQueens> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
```

The log and error:

```java
2019-06-21 11:50:28,951 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105 - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/C:/Users/s2932/.m2/repository/org/optaplanner/optaplanner-core/7.23.0.Final/optaplanner-core-7.23.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2019-06-21 11:50:28,953 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service +org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.kie.KieSolverAssemblerService

2019-06-21 11:50:28,953 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105 - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/C:/Users/s2932/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-decisiontables/7.23.0.Final/drools-decisiontables-7.23.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2019-06-21 11:50:28,954 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,955 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105 - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/C:/Users/s2932/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-compiler/7.23.0.Final/drools-compiler-7.23.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2019-06-21 11:50:28,960 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,962 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,962 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105 - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/C:/Users/s2932/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-core/7.23.0.Final/drools-core-7.23.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2019-06-21 11:50:28,963 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,964 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,965 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,965 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105 - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/C:/Users/s2932/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-internal/7.23.0.Final/kie-internal-7.23.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2019-06-21 11:50:28,966 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,966 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,967 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl

2019-06-21 11:50:28,967 INFO  ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:139 - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=kmodule.xml, line=0, column=0
   text=kmodule.xml found, but unable to read
]
---
Warning Messages:
---
Info Messages:

    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:607)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:410)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:334)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.app.NQueensHelloWorld.main(NQueensHelloWorld.java:33)
    at main.main(main.java:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

`kmodule.xml` is only needed in the classpath if you're use the "Kiecontainer" alternatives on the SolverFactory.create methods (hint: almost nobody does), or if you're using kie-server (some do this). Otherwise it's better not to have it in the classpath at all.